# Trying to echo line variable along with another variable inside a while read loop

Tags: unix, echo, readline

Am trying to echo a line variable along with another variable like below

```
while read -r line;do
id1=$(echo "$line"|grep...)
id2=`grep "$id1"...."
echo "$line" , "${id2}" >> file2.csv
done <$file1.csv
```

Expected output - `line,id2`

But the output in reality is like:
line

```
,id2line
```

What am I doing wrong here

Comment: That script doesn't compile (the backticked command substitution is missing the closing backtick). Also: what is the content of `"$file1.csv"` (that really should be quoted); what is the value of `$id1` and `$id2`; `echo "$line"` should ideally be `printf '%s\n' "$line"`; and `> file2.csv` can appear after the loop. Have you already run your file through https://www.shellcheck.net/?

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001